# Ruby on Rails - post id to start from 1 for each user

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I basically have `user has many posts` relationship setup among user, post model but I came to realise that I want to be able to provide each user with unique post ids.

So I guess each user should have their own posts table which can make the first post of each user start with `../posts/1`

Any idea where to go about this?

Comment: Done some research but haven't made a concrete start on this one yet as I'm not sure where to begin with and am wondering if rails has some useful resource that makes this easy.

Comment: You want find some library or gem for this? Or make it self?

Comment: I want to be able to get some basic ideas at least as I'm new to Rails.

Comment: Having a collection of tables for the same model would be rather difficult. Why do you need this? Also: What should happen if a user deletes a post, i.e. are gaps ok?

Comment: I just noticed that it's more common practice to hide any kind of id and use some kind of permalink instead like post title. Thanks

Comment: You should have another one attribute on `Post` model with integer type data (e.g `id_per_user`), because attribute id have auto-increment by rails. Before save a record, you can get with `find_by_user_id` and then get maximum of `id_per_user` from that, also plus 1 to that.

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track now. Add a **column** called `position` to your `Posts` model. Then you would have to use a gem for correctly positioning and repositioning on deletion of a `User`'s `Posts`. Have a look at [acts_as_tree](https://github.com/swanandp/acts_as_list/blob/master/README.md). There are other options as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want "slugs" to identify your posts.

Have a look at **[friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id)**, it simplifies a lot of slug related tasks.